# Strange Lucene error for IndexableField

Tags: java, lucene

We ran into this error accidentally. Here is how:

1. We had a Lucene search code based on Lucene version 3.6.0 working perfectly fine. The compilation of the code used to be against version 3.6.0.
2. The Lucene related jars which we use, are already there on server, so we do not bundle the Lucene jars with the deployment archive. The runtime refers the jars on the server.
3. Inadvertently, one of the team members compiled the code against Lucene 4.8.1 WITHOUT any code change.
4. When we deployed the code, we got `ClassNotFoundError` for `org/apache/lucene/index/IndexableField`. We are pretty sure that we DO NOT refer this class anywhere in our code, directly or indirectly. We searched and made sure of this using multiple tools.
5. We recompiled the code using version 3.6.0 then everything worked fine. The code compiles with 3.6.0 version without any problem.
6. The class `IndexableField` is only introduced in 4.8.1 version and its not here in any previous version.
7. We are using JDK7

Now the question is:

How does the compilation of same source using different library versions affect the **generated** bytecode ? In our code we never referred to `IndexableField`, but in the compile code, the reference to `IndexableField` creeps in when compiled against different version !

Comment: How is the code packaged?

Comment: Its packaged as a web application.

Comment: Lucene is split into multiple JARs, so you probably had a version mismatch with one of the JARs. Check the JAR versions in the WAR, one might be 3.6 and the other 4.8

Comment: There are no lucene jars in the WAR. Our project is bundled as EAR. The common lib folder in the EAR has as lucene related jar (version 3.6.0). What we do in the dev/test set up is, instead of deploying entire EAR, we just copy the WAR folder in EAR. The WAR refers the jars in common lib of EAR.